# Hive - select rows within 1 year of earliest date

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I am trying to select all rows in a table that are within 1 year of the earliest date in the table.  I'm using the following code:

```
select *
from baskets a
where activitydate < (select date_add((select min(activitydate) mindate_a from baskets), 365) date_b from baskets)
limit 10;
```

but get the following error message:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:55 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'date_add' '(' in expression specification 

    Total execution time: 00:00:00.338
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
With this code:

```
select *
from baskets a
where activitydate < (select date_add(min(activitydate), 365) from baskets)
limit 10;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:55 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'date_add' '(' in expression specification
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use window functions:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*, min(activity_date) as min_ad
      from baskets b
     ) b
where activity_date < add_months(min_ad, 12);
```

If you really want your syntax to work, try reducing the number of `select`s:

```
where activitydate < (select date_add(min(activitydate), 365) from baskets)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`s instead of select in Sub-query.  I don't think Hive supports select in where clause with `<` condition. Only `IN` and `EXISTS` could be used as of Hive 0.13.
 : [**Language Manual SubQueries**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   baskets a
       JOIN (SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(b.activitydate), 365) maxdate
             FROM   baskets) b
         ON a.activitydate < b.maxdate
LIMIT  10;
```